# react native error:——AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/inkcrazy/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/70043a6c1f9f43721644aa68c6c56b6f/core-1.7.0-beta02/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 11s

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hVAV.png)
Others are saying that 「androidx.core:core-ktx:+」 is the problem, but I can't find reliance on this library

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade react-native-community/netinfo package. In my case there was many package upgrade conflict, "yarn upgrade" solved problem for me.